# Feeding values from a c application to a shell continuously

Tags: c, bash, shell

My c program initates a i2c sensor that measures distance. In a permanent loop the programs takes one measurement and updates a variable:

```
while(1){
    ...
    uint16_t distance = readRangeSingleMillimeters();
    printf("Distance: %d\n", distance);
    fflush(stdout);
    ...
}
```

I have another c program with a few input arguments that can manipulate a LED light. I want the LED to blink faster with shorter distances.

I want a shell script that does exactly that. For that the measurement needs to take place in the background and somehow the shell must access the current distance of the c program. What's the easiest way to do that? just reading stdout seems to be the easiest solution to me.

Comment: Multithreading.

Comment: BTW: `printf("Distance: %d\n", distance);` -->> `printf("Distance: %hd\n", distance);`

Comment: If you don't want to read from `STDOUT`, You can print the distance from c program in a text file and then use the bash program to read the values from the file.